# Using the Metro-Style GridView without Grouping

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I have a simple collection like this:

```
Source
 - Feed (which has a "Title" propety)
   - Items (colleciton of other class)
```

I want to use the GridView for Metro-Style XAML project and I want to bind the header to the Title property of the Feed and the items of the collection to the ItemSource of the group. I'm baffled (since XAML binding failures don't show up in Output window or in another source).

I don't want to have to create an IGrouping or IGroupInfo to shoehorn the data into the control.

Any clues?

Comment: You'll need to tear out that part of the template.

Comment: I found the entire `SampleDataSource` structure confining and ended up editing the templates and code behind (remove Context, Items, etc...) heavily to make them work more to my liking and implement MVVM. Albeit, this was on the dev preview and not the consumer preview, so I'm not certain of all the differences at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the binding failures by enabling native debugging.  I wrote it up here http://www.kelvinhammered.com/?p=150